# rotation issue on physijs

Tags: javascript, three.js, physijs

I am working with this library for a short time, and i have a issue that is killing me.

I have 2 cubes, one with phisy.js and another with three.js, and i have a function for rotate them when you press the A, S, D, or W key depending on the rotation of the camera, my code is like this:

```
    var v = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    if (keys.forward === 1)
        v.x = -1;
    if (keys.right === 1)
        v.z = 1;
    if (keys.backward === 1)
        v.x = 1;
    if (keys.left === 1)
        v.z = -1;

    //get the searched angle
    var angle = camera.rotation.y + Math.atan2(v.x, v.z);
    var rot = normalMesh.rotation.y;
    var diff = angle - rot;

    if (Math.abs(diff) > Math.PI) {
        //find the shortest way to rotate
        if (diff > 0)
            rot += 2 * Math.PI;
        else
            rot -= 2 * Math.PI;
        diff = angle - rot;
    }
    //get the /2 for a smooth rotation, i really need this
    if (diff !== 0)
        rot += diff / 2;
    normalMesh.rotation.set(0, rot, 0);
```

on the three.js cube works fine, but on the physi.js cube i doesn't work.

I am created a demo for this (i can´t create it on jsfiddle because the web worker)

http://demo.cristobaldiaz.cl/test/

also i left the source code on a zip file ---> http://demo.cristobaldiaz.cl/test/issue.zip

you can check the movement function on http://demo.cristobaldiaz.cl/test/src/app.js line 95

Anyway, if you rotate the camera with the mouse, you can check that the problem occurs when you rotate the cube to the direction of the red mesh.

Comment: i had a similar problem with cannon.js (another physics engine) turned out i had to set the quaternions, not the rotation.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, i tried with quaternions, but it still failing.

Comment: Also i tried with matrix rotation with `actor.physiMesh.matrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion((new THREE.Quaternion()).setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(0, rot, 0, 'XYZ')));`
but nothing :(

Comment: well, physi.js is a physics engine, it would make sense to move the object by applying forces to it, rather than rotations or quaternions.

Comment: @KevinKuyl yes, i know that, but, i don't know what is the force for rotate.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove you rotation update from the animation loop and move it to  a physical loop:

```
scene.addEventListener('update', function(){
    actor.onRender();
})
```

This way it will always be in sync.

See this page https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/wiki/Callbacks-&-Events for more details.